# How do I simplify this javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, methods, attributes

It's the same effect but 4 different zoom elements.  How do I simplify this code?

```
<script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $('.etalage').etalage({
                show_hint: false,
                thumb_image_width: 470,
                thumb_image_height: 470,
                source_image_width: 1000,
                source_image_height: 1000,
                zoom_element: '#custom_zoom_element',
                //source_image_height: 480,
                //source_image_width: 480,
                zoom_area_width: 470,
                zoom_area_height: 470
            });
        });
```

It's the same effect but 4 different zoom elements.  How do I simplify this code?

```
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $('.etalage2').etalage({
                show_hint: false,
                    thumb_image_width: 470,
                thumb_image_height: 470,
                source_image_width: 1000,
                source_image_height: 1000,
                zoom_element: '#custom_zoom_element2',
                //source_image_height: 480,
                //source_image_width: 480,
                zoom_area_width: 470,
                zoom_area_height: 470
            });
        });
```

It's the same effect but 4 different zoom elements.  How do I simplify this code?

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
            $('.etalage3').etalage({
                show_hint: false,
                    thumb_image_width: 470,
                thumb_image_height: 470,
                source_image_width: 1000,
                source_image_height: 1000,
                zoom_element: '#custom_zoom_element3',
                //source_image_height: 480,
                //source_image_width: 480,
                zoom_area_width: 470,
                zoom_area_height: 470
            });
        });    

    $(document).ready(function(){
            $('.etalage4').etalage({
                show_hint: false,
                    thumb_image_width: 470,
                thumb_image_height: 470,
                source_image_width: 1000,
                source_image_height: 1000,
                zoom_element: '#custom_zoom_element4',
                //source_image_height: 480,
                //source_image_width: 480,
                zoom_area_width: 470,
                zoom_area_height: 470
            });
        });


    </script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple `for` will do it:

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
     for(var i=1; i <= 4; ++i){
        $('.etalage'+(i===1 ? '':i)).etalage({
            show_hint: false,
            thumb_image_width: 470,
            thumb_image_height: 470,
            source_image_width: 1000,
            source_image_height: 1000,
            zoom_element: '#custom_zoom_element'+(i===1 ? '':i),
            //source_image_height: 480,
            //source_image_width: 480,
            zoom_area_width: 470,
            zoom_area_height: 470
        });
     }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Give one more class say `foo` to all `etalage` elements

```
$(document).ready(function(){

        $('.foo').etalage({
                thumb_image_width: 470,
                thumb_image_height: 470,
                source_image_width: 1000,
                source_image_height: 1000,

    if($(this).hasClass('.etalage')){
               zoom_element: '#custom_zoom_element',
    }else if($(this).hasClass('.etalage2')){
              zoom_element: '#custom_zoom_element2',

    }
    }else if($(this).hasClass('.etalage3')){
              zoom_element: '#custom_zoom_element3',

    }
    }else if($(this).hasClass('.etalage4')){
           zoom_element: '#custom_zoom_element4',

    }
         zoom_area_width: 470,
         zoom_area_height: 470
});
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the $.extend function to simplify as below..

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var defaultOpts = {
        show_hint: false,
        thumb_image_width: 470,
        thumb_image_height: 470,
        source_image_width: 1000,
        source_image_height: 1000,
        zoom_element: '#xyz',
        zoom_area_width: 470,
        zoom_area_height: 470
    };
    $(".id1").etalage(defaultOpts);
    $(".id2").etalage($.extend({},defaultOpts,{zoom_element:"#abc"}));
    $(".id3").etalage($.extend({},defaultOpts,{zoom_element:"#def"}));
});
```

With the above approach, one can override any of the properties just by changing the third parameter of extend function..